# How to change default date column in sharepoint calendar 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

Would like to know how to change the default date column in sharepoint calendar. Am using 2 date and time column (Start Date and End Time) DEFAULT and (Online Availability and Start & End Time). I'd like to use the second one to appear in the calendar. Is it possible?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the calendar list setting page, click on add from existing site column, there you add your new date columns and can remove the old date columns.

And also if you want to handle this through calendar event content type, go to the site content type page from site setting page, search for **Event** content type, from there remove your old date columns from that content type and add the new date columns to the **Event** content type.